# Mailchimp wordpress blog automation bug (no RSS feed)

Tags: wordpress, blogs, mailchimp, newsletter

I'm trying to do an automated newsletter of my wordpress blog on mailchimp.
I've several categories of posts on my blog and i'd like to display them separately in my newsletter.
I used this code in my mailchimp campaign but I doesn't display articles from the category i choose...
If you have 1 min to check it and help me it would be very nice!

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

```html
*|FEEDBLOCK:http://www.le-meilleur-quartier.fr/feed[$category=jeux]|*
*|FEEDITEMS:[$count=1]|*
<h2 class="null">*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|*</h2>
*|FEEDITEM:CONTENT|*
<h2 class="null"><span style="font-size:17px"><a href="*|FEEDITEM:SOURCE|*" target="_blank">Lire l'article</a></span></h2>
*|END:FEEDITEMS|*
*|END:FEEDBLOCK|*
```

Comment: PS: I've also tried this but it displays nothing...

*|FEEDBLOCK:http://www.le-meilleur-quartier.fr/feed|*
*|FEEDITEMS:[$count=1, $category=jeux]|*
<h2 class="null">*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|*</h2>
*|FEEDITEM:CONTENT|*

<h2 class="null"><span style="font-size:17px"><a href="*|FEEDITEM:SOURCE|*" target="_blank">Lire l'article</a></span></h2>
*|END:FEEDITEMS|*
*|END:FEEDBLOCK|*

Comment: up please ! :'(